# How to mix rules depending on field in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there any possibility to allow all users (no auth users) to write / update only one field in a collection? Something like this -

```
"foobar": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != null",
  "foo": {
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Is this for firebase database, storage or firestore?

Comment: Yes I have try it and its not working. The rule are for Firebase database.

Comment: In that case it would help if you add the read/write code you are using that is failing for you. The rules you have here now seem to be correct.

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome but not in Safari. Really strange.

Comment: I think this question needs an [mcve] to be answerable.